# How to convert JDeveloper created BPEL process to WSO2 BPEL Process

Tags: oracle, wso2, jdeveloper, bpel

I have an old set of BPEL processes which were created using JDeveloper. I want to import it to WSO2 integration studio and make a WSO2-server-deployable archive. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think so there would be any automated tool/script for this, as The BPEL notation is evolving (e.g. stanrd is now 2.0, and I assume that your old processes uses 1.3) and moreover oracle uses custom build bpel extensions which of course WSO2 does not use, and thus can not be converted.

I think you have to rewrite your bpel processes, which is time consuming however this task can do some good as refactoring is always a good move to do!

Comment: I second this, during refactoring hash some of the code that is not used any more and streamline processes which have been added to over the course of the years. I recently had to do this with a customer and it actually was a ton of fun, best way to learn the running network of the company. Did cost us a couple of months though. You might be able to sell it as a plus if you encorporate some plans for the refactoring.